# PySpark Conversion to Array Types

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently dealing with the following error while trying to run `pyspark.sql.functions.explode` on a array column in a DataFrame in PySpark. I've tried creating a UDF to convert the column to a python list if it is not a list instance. However, this still throws the same error. In Pandas I'd typically pull out the row and determine what to do from there. I'm not sure how I can access this row to look at the data to understand what conditions I need to account for.

I'm more looking for debugging advice in general, but if you know the answer that's great too!

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2850.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`lot`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not LongType;;`

```
df.schema()

root
 |-- lists: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- data: string (nullable=true)

df = df.withColumn("list",df.lists)
df = df.withColumn('list',sf.explode(df.list))
```

## Original Code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf 

# create duplicate column to use with explode 
# explode the array datetype into multiple rows per element 

df = spark.read("s3a://path/parquet/*")     
df = df.withColumn("list",df.lists)
df = df.withColumn('list',sf.explode(df.list))
```

Comment: can you please post the code snippet of the problem, that will be much helpful in debugging or finding out the probelem

Comment: *please*, do not post code snippets in the comments! Edit your post instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to used withcolumn you can directly explode the array.

```
df = spark.read("s3a://path/parquet/*")     
df.select(df['data'],explode(df['lists']).alias('list'))
```

Comment: if you want original `lists` column with this then you can also select `lists`.